# Where to start profiling Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, profiling

What are the standard and conventional ways of profiling the Linux kernel? I know there is `perf` tool but is there anything else?

Comment: What more do you need? Typing your question title in google gives a lot of interesting reading already - what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you using [SystemTap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) using which you can add probe points to a running linux kernel. It is similar to `DTrace` which is similar tool developed for Solaris. You can write simple stap script to perform interesting tasks.